# Largest curvature congruent to $2, 3, 6, 11 (\text{mod } 12)$ missing from Apollonian gasket $(-1,2,2,3)$

Tags: number-theory

Consider the Apollonian gasket $(-1,2,2,3)$. It is conjectured that every number congruent to $2, 3, 6, 11 (\text{mod } 12)$ appears as a curvature of a circle inside the gasket, except for a finite sequence of integers.

I wrote a little program that searches for those integers and the largest number $\lt 10^6$ it could find is $97287$.

My question is if there is a greater number known that belongs to the sequence.

Comment: conjectured where?

Comment: @WillJagy I'm not sure where it is conjectured, but it is mentioned at the bottom of this page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BowlofIntegers.html

Comment: In Graham et al, J. N. T. (2003) pages 1-45, it is the Strong Density Conjecture on page 37. It is then repeated for your case on page 42. They do a large computation but for a different packing. http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/03_02_appolonian.pdf    see also http://oeis.org/A042944  and  http://oeis.org/A042945 OEIS cites Wilks (2002), he is one of the authors in 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it an answer, this is the Strong Density Conjecture on page 37 of [GRAHAM ET AL](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/03_02_appolonian.pdf) They do a big computer run, but for a different packing, page 38. Then they briefly repeat the conjecture for this packing on page 42.

There is progress on the density conjecture by [BOURGAIN AND KONTOROVICH](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4416).  In particular, they show that there are a positive constant $C$ and a positive exponent $0 <p < 1,$ dependent on the specific packing, such that the number of missing admissible numbers (up to large $N$) is less than 
$$ C N^p. $$ In your case, admissible would be $2,3,6, 11 \pmod{12}.$ This means that the set of numbers that occur has full density among those permitted by congruences; it does not quite show finiteness. This is a big advance; Graham et al were not, originally, able to prove the numbers that occur had nonzero (upper) density.

You have the option of contributing a better b-file compared with http://oeis.org/A042945   and https://oeis.org/A042945/b042945.txt  as your output goes higher, they stop at 13154.